# Why is my C++ code returning some weird numbers even though everything is correct?

Tags: c++

Why is this program returning random letters after output?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int guessIt(int num) {
    if(num == 27) {
        cout << "You Won";
    }
    else {
        cout << "You Lost";
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << guessIt(27);
}
```

Comment: Please put a [mre] in the question as text instead of linking to a picture

Comment: Post all necessary information into the question itself. Put in code and error messages as formatted code blocks. Never provide code or error messages in images or links to external sites.

Comment: You declared your function as `int` but you do not ***return*** any values.

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior. Your function promised to return an int but broke that promise. There is no `return` statement in the `guessIt()` function. I think you really wanted `void guessIt(int num) {` and then change `cout << guessIt(27);` to `guessIt(27);`

Comment: Since there is no `return` statement in `guessIt()`, change its return type to `void` instead of `int`, and then get rid of the `cout` statement in `main()` since it is useless anyway.  Otherwise, rewrite the code to get rid of the `cout` statements in `guessIt()` and instead `return` whatever you want `main()` to print.

Comment: *even though everything is correct* ... You should enable warnings on your compiler, it should have been able to point out where something was not correct.

Comment: [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0447c53cb6f8a620).  Your compiler should have (or it would be nice to have) a warning like that.

Comment: _even though everything is correct_  -- famous last words.  Welcome to c++.  :)  Always turn up warnings to the max, and ask your compiler to treat warnings as errors.  Never ignore them.

Comment: [Here are the mistakes in your code](https://godbolt.org/z/fYdxK16eh), as reported by the three major compilers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems in your code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int guessIt(int num) { //when you make the function guessIt(int num) you say it returns an int
    if(num == 27) {
        cout << "You Won";
    }
    else {
        cout << "You Lost";
    }
} //code finished without returning an int

int main() {
    cout << guessIt(27); //What happens here? guessIt didn't return anything, so cout prints something it got that was in the memory where guessIt was supposed to put it's return value
}
```

What you have to do is either add returns, like `return 0;` if you win and `return 1;` if you lost instead of `cout<<"You won";` or `cout<<"You Lost";` Then in main() add

```
if (guessIt(27)==0) {
//TODO: Win message here
}
else {
//TODO: Lose message here
}
```

You can also change guessIt's return value to `void`, and remove the `cout<<guessIt(27)` and just have `guessIt(27)`. (`void` means it will return nothing.)